# PHONEGAP/WP8: FileTransfer not sending session cookies

Tags: cookies, cordova, windows-phone-8, file-transfer

The server I'm using sends the session id with a http-only cookie.
To make this working on WP8, I already enabled cookies in the internet explorer settings of the device. This works well for all my AJAX-requests.
But now i have to download a file from the server, therefore I'm using the file-transfer plugin, but i always get `HTTP Status 401 - Http Request not attached to a session`
Is there any way to fix this issue, so that the cookie header containing the JSESSIONID is sent with the download request?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution or a work-around?

Comment: Try this [fork](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/pull/90)